# BIM 360 Extensions in Autodesk Forge

Tags: autodesk-forge, forge, autodesk-bim360

I am interested in such a difficult question. Is it possible to use the extension from BIM360 in a project on Autodesk forge?
For example, I want to use the pushpin extension from BIM360 in forge viewer.
I have tried to do it with forge point cloud pushpins but have troubles and it not work.

Comment: like your other questions without any specific details it’s difficult to know what went wrong

Comment: the problem is that all functions work but pushpins do not appear on the model.